# Altering a COUNT to a COUNTIF to count 100 values across a number of sheets

Tags: excel, count, countif

I've inherited a spreadsheet at work and I want to edit it to suit my needs. It currently uses the following formula to count row values across various sheets (including 0 values).

=IF(ISERROR(COUNT(INDIRECT($A5&"F"&MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0)&":IV"&MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0)))),"",COUNT(INDIRECT($A5&"F"&MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0)&":IV"&MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0))))

Now, I'd like to amend this formula so that it only counts values that are =100. I assume this would mean using the COUNTIF function but I can't quite work it out as it is quite a complicated formula for me. Hopefully this is an easy fix for someone who knows what they are doing.

It is for test scores. Say in the row someone has 100, 90, 100, 90, 100. It is currently bringing back the result of 5. I'd like to alter this so it brings back a result of 3 as there were three 100 scores. Obviously it is a little more complicated because it is working across a range of sheets (1 person = 1 sheet) and it is bringing back results for as many as 20 people on some of these workbooks.

Thanks in advance. Really appreciate it!

Comment: We'd really appreciate the relevant sample of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Excel 2007` or later then you can use this formula to count 100s in the relevant range - using `IFERROR` for error checking purposes, i.e.

`=IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDEX(INDIRECT($A5&"F1:IV13"),MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0),0),100),0)`

or in earlier versions of Excel try

`=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,IF({1,0},0,COUNTIF(INDEX(INDIRECT($A5&"F1:IV13"),MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($A5&"B1:B13"),0),0),100)))`